# Array of one value, for every integer in another field?

Tags: mysql

I'm stumped on this one, I have the following:

```
Color  Qty  Length
('Blue', 5, 50),
('Blue', 1, 500),
('Blue', 1, 250),
('Green', 4, 175),
('Green', 2, 35),
('Green', 2, 80)
```

I need an array that groups by color, showing the length for each qty, by that I mean:

```
Blue: 50,50,50,50,50,500,250
Green: 175,175,175,175,35,35,80,80
```

I've tried all sorts of `GROUP_CONCAT`/`CONCAT` combinations but I am stuck on getting the length column to repeat for every qty.

I have a sqlfiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f796b).

Is it even possible? :)

Answer (score 1):

Figured this out if anyone comes across this and wants the solution:

```
SELECT color, TRIM(TRAILING ',' FROM GROUP_CONCAT(REPEAT(CONCAT(length,','),qty) SEPARATOR '') ) 
FROM buyer_advert 
GROUP BY color
```

This makes a nice array like I wanted.

Comment: Don't forget to use the editing tools that are above the box where you type in questions and answers! Help us to help you :-)